# Log Memcached Activity

Tags: memcached

I'm looking to log all activity going on in my memcached server. All reads and writes.

This is going to be used as a distributed daemon for lots of remote php apps in the cloud and need a way to SSH in and check out the activity going on, on the daemon.

I've googled extensively and can't find a single way to do this.

The Redis equivalent would be logging into the interactive console and typing MONITOR.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create an API to access memcache, and put the logging at this layer. But I guess it defeat the purpose of having a fast performance storage.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using memcached's telnet `stats` command as such :

- enable capturing information : `stats detail on`
- wait a while
- disable capturing : `stats detail off`
- dump the information : `stats detail dump`

`telnet yourhost 11211` and run the sequence above. Note that this will impact greatly the performance.

Also you could check out [phpmemcacheadmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/) - it's a really nice tool for monitoring memcached pools.

Comment: I did "stats detail on" - then what? Where is the log?

Answer (score 8):

You can start your memcached using the -vv parameter:

```
-vv           very verbose (also print client commands/reponses)
```

The output is similar to this:

```
Dec 12 10:33:12 hostname memcached[18350]: <33 new auto-negotiating client connection
Dec 12 10:33:12 hostname memcached[18350]: 33: Client using the ascii protocol
Dec 12 10:33:12 hostname memcached[18350]: <33 set your.key.1 3 300 525
Dec 12 10:33:12 hostname memcached[18350]: >33 STORED
Dec 12 10:33:12 hostname memcached[18350]: <33 get your.key.2
Dec 12 10:33:12 hostname memcached[18350]: >33 sending key your.key.2
Dec 12 10:33:12 hostname memcached[18350]: >33 END
```

The output is sent to stdout, so you might want to redirect it to some file.

Answer (score 0):

Use supervisord to run memcached. It'll log the memcached output (based on the 1,2 or 3 -v's) to syslog - so log rotate should work (it won't if you just pipe output to a file) and you can use syslog to send all the logs to a central logging machine (using something like graylog2 to take all the log info).

Comment: Can you provide an example please?